# Getting a control from a DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Assuming that I have an arbitrary control inside a DataGridTemplateColumn, I wish to know how to get the control, given that I have retrieved the DataGridCell which contains that control.

My XAML file containing the DataGrid is as follows:

```xml
    <DataGrid Name="dgMovement">
...    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Target %">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <vi:PercentageEditor Value="{Binding TargetPercentage, Mode=TwoWay,
                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100px"  
                      cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewLostKeyboardFocus] = [Action ChangeTargetPercentage];[Event PreviewGotKeyboardFocus] = [Action OnFocus]" 
                      Name="aa" />
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>...
```

I retrieved the DataGridCell using extension methods as follows:

```
DataGridCell cell = view.dgMovement2.GetCell(index, 6);
```

The extension methods, contained in a static class is found [here](http://code.google.com/p/artur02/source/browse/trunk/DataGridExtensions/DataGridHelper.cs)

The question is, how to I retrieve the "PercentageEditor", once I got the DataGridCell? Can anybody help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the name of the control to find it in the template, e.g.

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <uc:Bogus x:Name="root" ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

```cs
var cell = dataGrid.GetCell(5, 0);
var cp = (ContentPresenter)cell.Content;
var bogus = (Bogus)cp.ContentTemplate.FindName("root", cp);
```

---

Note however that this usually should *not* be necessary as modifying templated controls for the most part can be done using data binding, attached properties and events alone. In general i would restrict template access via code to custom controls (which often have [designated parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: Glad it helped :) (You could accept this answer by clicking the checkmark outline on the left of it)

Comment: A couple of years later i still found thia useful. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me (C#)

```
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgContacts.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            var cell = dgContacts.Columns[0];

            var cp = (ContentPresenter)cell.GetCellContent(row);
            CheckBox rowSelected = (CheckBox)cp.ContentTemplate.FindName("Edit", cp);
```