# WPF DataGrid with formatted text cells

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

In a setting with `AutoGenerateColmns=True`, I’m trying to find a way that would allow me to display multi-colored text within a single cell of a C# `DataGrid` in WPF. Both a solution with a custom cell template or with a HTML interpreter inside the cell would do; for technical reasons I’d prefer the first option, but I spent a lot of time trying to get any of these working, to no avail.

An additional problem is that I’m dealing with several tables here that I’ve got to display using the same User Control. Only one of the tables will require text formatting. I’ve figured out how to dynamically change the nature of the table based on a criterion of my choice, but I don’t know how to fill these modified cells based on the actual text that goes in there. The text itself contains a token (`"|||"`—three pipes) at which to split the string; one is to be displayed in blue, the other in red.

Let me show you my code. I’ll start with an excerpt from `App.xaml` so that it’s clear how I’ve set up my `DataGrid` style-wise.

### My `App.xaml`

As you’ll see, I need to have the `DataGrid` auto-generate the columns, since I’m working on a database whose schema is not known to me at compile time. Since the table headers may contain underscores, I’ve created a custom template that does not treat underscores in the usual fashion, i.e., as short hand key combos with Alt.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
  <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

### The `DataGrid` itself

This has some modifications, one of which is that I’m using a custom `RowDetailsTemplate` based on another User Control. This is of no concern (I hope), but I leave it in here for the sake of completeness (and in case there are some side effects that I’m missing). `ExpView` is the namespace I’m working in; “Exp” itself is what the software is called (which is why the ancestor item of the `DataGrid` is called “`ExpView:ExpResultsTable`”).

You see that I subscribe to two events here. I’ve tried as much as possible to keep my code-behind empty (as recommended in the MSDN docs for a clean MVVM implementation), but there’s only so much one can do with XAML alone, I fear… Feel free to correct me, though. These events are what I use in order to determine whether the `DataGrid` is going to be for the special table or the normal ones.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid_Calibs"
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCalib,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ExpView:ExpResultsTable}}"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_Calibs_AutoGeneratingColumn"
          LoadingRow="DataGrid_Calibs_LoadingRow">
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ExpView:CalibrationDetails/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

I also have at the beginning of this XAML file the following resource declaration that goes into the cells in case I’ve got to display the “special” table.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DifferenceDataTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldValue_Old" Foreground="Blue"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldValue_New" Foreground="Red"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The plan is to populate the table with the normal data binding if it’s got to display normal data. (I don’t populate the `DataGrid` with `RowView`s; instead I’m binding the `DataGrid` to objects that properly exhibit public properties. You’ll see the effect of this in my event handler code below.) If the data is “special”, I want to replace the cells with the `StackPanel` defined in the resources above, and set the contents of both `TextBlock`s (or `Label`s, if these turn out to work better) with respect to the first and second part of the string supposed to go into the cell, split at `"|||"`.

### The event handlers in the code-behind

The beautiful thing about the WPF event handler for auto-generating a `DataGrid`’s columns is that it does its normal job unless you explicitly overwrite the column. This is why the following code works fine in replacing the `DataGrid`’s cells with the aforementioned `StackPanel` only in case I discover a “special table”.

```
private void DataGrid_Calibs_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
  ParameterDetails parameterDetailsControl = ((ScrollViewer)((DockPanel)((StackPanel)((DataGrid)sender).Parent).Parent).Parent).Parent as ParameterDetails;
  ExpUserInterface parent = Window.GetWindow((DependencyObject)parameterDetailsControl) as ExpUserInterface;
  ExpResultsTable resultsTableControl = parent.ResultsTable.Content as ExpResultsTable;
  string selector = resultsTableControl.SelectedTabItem.Header.ToString();

  if (selector.Equals("special")) {
    DifferenceDataTemplateColumn col = new DifferenceDataTemplateColumn();
    col.Header = e.PropertyName;
    col.CellValue = e.PropertyName;
    col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("DifferenceDataTemplate");
    col.CellTemplate.DataType = typeof(MyDatabaseObject);
    col.IsReadOnly = true;
    e.Column = col;
  }
}

private void DataGrid_Calibs_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) {
  MyDatabaseObject calib = e.Row.DataContext as MyDatabaseObject;
  // anything I can do about the problem in here?
}
```

The second event handler is here mostly to show you that I’m indeed binding to `MyDatabaseObject` instead of a `RowView`.

I readily admit that the first four lines are ugly, but at least they work for now. Any suggestions are welcome, though.

The rest works fine, too: the “normal” tables populate as planned, and the “special” table is formatted with my custom `StackPanels` in every cell. However, I don’t succeed in filling these cells.

### The questions

Here’s what I’ve been pondering on for days now, and which I can’t figure out querying the usual suspects (Stackoverflow, MSDN, etc.):

- How can I access the cell’s contents? The `LoadingRow` event is where I should access the string, split it, and set `FieldValue_Old.Text` and `FieldValue_New.Text`. I can access the object via `calib` (see above)—the debugger shows that I’m right there—but I can’t for the life of me figure out how to access the `TextBlock`s of a single (“special”) cell, let alone how to do this for all columns of the row at hand.
- Can I maybe solve this using a `CellTemplateSelector`? How?
- Am I using the right event handler? Is there an event that I should prefer over these?
- Is there any other way to achieve this result? For instance, can I convince a `DataGrid` to interpret HTML in its cells? (I don’t need to worry about code injection here, since I’d only be generating HTML code at the very moment of filling the `DataGrid`.)

Any help is highly appreciated and will keep me from rapidly approach baldness as I’m tearing my hair out over this. Thank you!

### Update

I forgot to add the code for the custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` that I’ve been referring to in the aforementioned `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler.

```
public class DifferenceDataTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn {
    public string CellValue { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) {
      ContentPresenter presenter = (ContentPresenter)base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
      BindingOperations.SetBinding(presenter, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.CellValue));
      return presenter;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I’ve been really close to the solution; it can be achieved without resorting to `DataGrid_Calibs_LoadingRow` or a `TemplateSelector`. We still need the `DataGrid_Calibs_AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler, but only in order to properly apply the custom cell template with the two `TextBlock`s, and we still need the custom `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

### The new user control XAML code

The trick was to extend the user control’s resource definitions.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DifferenceDataTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldValue_Old" Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource fieldValueConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource True}}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldValue_New" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource fieldValueConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource False}}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

### Additions to `App.xaml`

I’ve defined the converter in a manner that allows it to be used for both `TextBlock`s, but in order to do so, I need to pass a `bool`. Since XAML, by default, passes `ConverterParameter`s as `string`, I defined two new resources in my `App.xaml` in addition to the `fieldValueConverter`.

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
             ... >
  <Application.Resources>
    <MyNamespace:FieldValueConverter x:Key="fieldValueConverter" />
    <s:Boolean x:Key="True">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="False">False</s:Boolean>
    ...
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

### Additions to `App.xaml.cs`

The remaining thing to do is to define the actual value converter in `App.xaml`’s code-behind.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
public class FieldValueConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    bool isOld = (bool)parameter;
    string[] fieldValues = value.ToString().Split(new string[] {"|||"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

    string fieldValue = "";
    if (isOld)
      fieldValue = fieldValues[0];
    else if (!isOld && fieldValues.Length == 2)
      fieldValue = fieldValues[1];
    return fieldValue;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Back conversion of comparison fields is not supported.");
  }
}
```

The only reason for the `fieldValues.Length == 2` check is that, for fields that don’t contain the string `"|||"`, I don’t want the second field to display anything. Also, since the fields containing no difference are by default empty, I return the empty string by default.

And that’s all that was missing! It works like a charm now.

### Bonus question

I don’t see why the custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` is needed. It provides another property to access what I call the `CellValue` above, since my data binding would elsewise just call the `ToString()` method on the bound objects, i.e., the cells contain the object name, not the field value. But why?

### Acknowledgements

Many thanks go to the answers posted to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315611/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-how-to-color-paint-text-inside-datagrid-cells-without-brea?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997446/boolean-commandparameter-in-xaml) question here on StackOverflow.