# WPF - How to access a control in a GridView templated cell

Tags: wpfdatagrid

There are similar topics here, but none of the resolutions have helped me.

I have the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PlateWellControlTemplate"
                             TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_stateGrid"
                      Margin="0,0,5,0">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#FF252526"
                             MinWidth="34"
                             MinHeight="34"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="PART_stateControl"
                             Fill="#FFE6E6E6"
                             MinWidth="32"
                             MinHeight="32"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold"
                           FontFamily="Verdana"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           Background="#00000000"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Content=""/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Used here:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="2">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Tag="{Binding WellX2}" 
                              x:Name="wellX2" 
                              MouseDown="well_Click">
                            <ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource PlateWellControlTemplate}"/>
```

Then accessed here in code-behind:

```
DataTemplate cellTemplate = (DataTemplate)cell.Template.FindName("PART_stateControl", cell);
```

Where "cell" is a non-null DataGridCell using the template.  The above line always returns null and I do not understand why.  I have also tried as a ControlTemplate and a ContentPresenter.

**What I need is a reference to the Ellipse** ("PART_StateControl") in the DataGridCell I've been handed as I need to change one of it's properties.  But in general, how do I get to named items in the ContentControl Template?  This is all triggered by a click event on the parent Grid control referenced in the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate here named "wellX2".  Again, there are a few discussions on here regarding this, but none have helped.  I feel like there's something silly missing.  This has to be doable.

Thanks in advance for any help you can afford.

Comment: Just FYI, I already am aware that: DataTemplate cellTemplate = (DataTemplate)cell.Template.FindName("PART_stateControl", cell); is attempting to access the incorrect item name.  This was only due to me trying several things and not correcting this one last item before I posted.  What I'm really trying to get is:  Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)cell.Template.FindName("PART_stateControl", cell); but this also returns null.  It's not the cast that's an issue either.  Even casting as "object" returns null.

Comment: (Ellipse)cell.Template.FindName("PART_stateControl", cell); seems fishy.  Mainly because I'm making a call on cell and handing it cell.

Answer (score 1):

Answer found as a combination of this:

[Getting a control from a DataGridCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098475/getting-a-control-from-a-datagridcell)

and this:

[How to Get element inside the content control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904989/how-to-get-element-inside-the-content-control)

Brilliant!